# What number object should I use, need to convert 1.4 from NSString and do an If less than?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnumber

What number object should I use i've tried double but it converts 1.4 to 1.39999999

I've also tried NSNumber but I can't find out how to do.

```
if (MyNum < 1.4) {
```

Also I need to convert from an NSString

I'm evaluation my app version number 1.4 is my new release version. I need to perform action if (appVer < 1.4)

Comment: also, I don't think 1.4 has an exact representation in binary.  Not all numbers can be represented in decimal, and nor can all numbers be represented in floating point numbers. You will need to settle on an approximation. What is it you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSString`'s built-in number conversion methods.

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]infoDictionary]objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
double versionNumber = [version doubleValue];
```

Then use:

```
if (versionNumber < 1.4) {
```

[NSString Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Comment: @Rudy: True, version 1.10 after 1.9 will require a custom parser!

Answer (score 2):

What sort of result do you want?  If you want a floating point result then you tend to get 1.39999999, because there's no exact representation of 1.4 in IEEE float.

As far as I know Objective-C does not have a decimal type, so if you wish to have an exact representation you must use integers and keep track of the decimal point yourself.  Any arithmetic then becomes fairly complicated.

[I see that there is indeed NSDecimalNumber, which should do most of what is needed.  Have no experience with it, however.]

Your best bet is probably to use floating point and rely on rounding during formatting, unless you need financial accuracy.

Comment: @Jules: In floating-point, there is no 1.4. Fortunately, this means that `1.4` is not exactly 1.4 either, so Evan Mulawski's solution is likely to work out anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need such accuracy, use `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: Update the answer with http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/23/cocoa-tutorial-dont-be-lazy-with-nsdecimalnumber-like-me/ but please don't say that it's more "accurate", rather, you have less conversion error. It's more "accurate" because you're not converting. Like floating point numbers, decimal can't represent all numbers either.

Comment: @Arafangion: NSdecimalNumber gives a higher precision, and it certainly won't have problems converting from a string representating a decimal. Since his number is supposed to be a **version number**, decimal is exactly what he needs.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: That's a new addition to his question - yep, I will agree, using decimal in a version number with a single decimal point is ideal, although it won't be satisfactory for most version numbers, particularly those of a.b.c or a.b.c.d formats - for those, you'll have to either use a string, or four ints.

Comment: @Arafangion: I agree. I would use something different.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: Would NSDecimalNumber store '1.10' as '1.1' or would it retain the tailing '0'?

Comment: @Arafangion: I just checked, and apparently it does not distinguish between 1.10 and 1.1. I recently wrote a Decimal type for Delphi, and that **does** remember the number of decimal digits entered. This one doesn't. But even my Decimal type would compare 1.1 and 1.10 as equal, even if they are represented differently internally.

Answer (score 1):

In order to correctly handle version numbers like 1.10 (which `floatValue` and friends will interpret as a single number, which would be 1.1), you should borrow [Growl's version-comparison code](http://growl.info/hg/growl/file/2e787f50d3c7/Common/Source/GrowlVersionUtilities.c) under [their BSD license](http://growl.info/hg/growl/file/2e787f50d3c7/License.txt).

Answer (score -3):

A few things

(1) NSNumber is an integer type, according to [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It cannot represent 1.4.

(2) EDIT: see my comment about Major/Minor/Patch version numbers below. You didn't exactly explain that 1.4 represented a fixed version number that should be broken into sub-parts.

Comment: `NSNumber` can represent floats and doubles.

Comment: I'm evaluation my app version number 1.4 is my new release version. I need to perform action if (appVer < 1.4)

Comment: I understood you need it as an app version. 1.399999 (double) is good enough, since your other version numbers will be far enough away. Even if 1.3 is stored as 1.300001, it will still be < 1.3999999.

Comment: FWIW, as I asked in another comment, what comes after 1.9? Note that 1.10 is numerically the same as 1.1, so perhaps numerals are not such a good idea, even if comparing them is easier.

Comment: For app versions, the commonly accepted way to do it is to have an integer for majorVersion (=1) minorVersion (4) and soforth. Then you can evaluate ( majorVersion >= 1 && minorVersion >= 4 ). This solves the version 1.10 problem as well. You can have as many "blocks" as you want. 

For a learn-by-example ideas, see the GNU GCC versioning here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html